# Pandas Dataframe: Lack of Memory- What's the better way here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
f = pd.read_hdf('Sensor_Data.h5','f')
pieces = [f[x: x + 360] for x in xrange(504649)]
df = pd.concat(pieces)
```

Morning all. I have a file with 500,000+ rows of data. I want to take 360 row slices from this, and move it down by 1 row each time. (So I will end up with a LOT of data. )

As expected, I tried the above code and got a memory error. I'm assuming there's a better way of doing this?

EDIT: To add some context, this is a .h5 file, and I'm using pandas dataframe to try and slice it this way. I'm trying to create an array of data to feed into a deep neural network using caffenet, though the format it will be in at this point will be unclear...

The code works for small amounts of data. Just not for larger ones. To be clearer of what I'm trying to do:import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,6)); df
```

[displays a 6 x 10 table of random numbers]
Now:

```
pieces = [df[x: x + 4] for x in xrange(7)]
f = pd.concat(pieces)
f
```

Diplays a new table similar to the previous one, but expanded. It now has rows 0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6...

Now "pieces" is not a dataframe object itself, but a 'list' for some reason. Is there also a simple way to turn all of these separate datasets (0,1,2,3),(1,2,3,4) and so on, into dataframe object themselves? (Instead of concatenating them together into one dataframe?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: My preferred way of handling large amounts of data is using [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html). One downside is that you have to convert your data into a binary format that can be understood by `memmap`, but after that you can easily work with huge datasets.

Do you really need to store all this redundant data for your slices? What is the ultimate use of these slices? Maybe it would be better to just create an iterator.

Comment: Well, you're basically taking your data and multiplying by 360, right?  But this final dataframe is filled with tons of redundant data, which is pointless.  I guess you are doing this for purposes of later calculations?  But there are going to be better ways to do those calculations than wasting memory.  e.g. moving/expanding functions, advanced (fancy) indexing, etc.  I suspect what you need to do is think about how to do the calcs, not how to expand the memory footprint.

Comment: Yes, it is for the purposes of later calcs. I'll edit the question to be a bit clearer... what should I do given the new context?

Comment: General way to go here is usually:  make example dataframe (as small as possible), show desired output, show the actual code you have attempted to write.  Also see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Consider using h5py. From [the website](http://www.h5py.org/): "For example, you can slice into multi-terabyte datasets stored on disk, as if they were real NumPy arrays".

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of questions there. First the easiest: pieces is a list because you've created it using a list comprehension, it should be a list of dataframe objects. If you want to use them as separate data frame objects you could just index into the list (i.e. pieces[0] etc).

But you still have this problem that you are trying to create a huge data frame. Without seeing the rest of how you would use the code I'd suggest not create half a million slices of your df but instead looping over you original data frame and calling whatever function you need on a single slice of the data frame:

```
for x in xrange(504649):
    result = my_func(df[x:x+360])
```

that way each slice is released after its used. And hopefully the result is much smaller than the frame.

You could also similarly as above write all our slices to separate cvs files and read them in as you need.